# Mapping An Entity Property To A Different Table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two entities:

```
public class User 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class Product 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string CreatedUserName { get; set }
}
```

My database schema contains a foreign key in `Products` table pointing to the `Id` column in the `Products` table. I need a way to tell Entity Framework to navigate the foreign key and get the value of the `UserName` column for the `CreatedUserName` property.

Is this possible? I don't want the product to have the entire User entity.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean that foreign key points to the User table? I think what you need to look at is independent associations where you have navigation properties on your entities but foreign keys are not exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible? I don't want the product to have the entire User entity.

No unless you want to do a database view for your product. What you tries to map is not a real entity anymore. It is more like a view model so why not to use projection?

```
var productView = context.Products
                         .Where(p => p.Id == ...)
                         .Select(p => new ProductView {
                             Id = p.Id,
                             Name = p.Name,
                             CreatedUserName = p.User.UserName
                         });
```

Answer (score 3):

I was looking into the same thing and found a technique called 'Entity Splitting'
http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/Entity-Splitting-in-Code-First-Entity-Framework.aspx

So based on your code it looks like you could do:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity()
        // Map to the Product table
        .Map(map =>
        {
            map.Properties(p => new {
                p.Id,
                p.Name
            });

            map.ToTable("Product");
        })
        // Map to the User table
        .Map(map =>
        {
            map.Properties(p => new {
                p.CreatedUserName
            });

            map.ToTable("User");
        });
}
```